# Is there an established software taxonomy that's based on the type of software?

Tags: development-process, software

I'm researching engineering approaches to software development based on the type of software, for example:

- Custom one-off software (e.g. space shuttle software)
- Whitebox application requiring customised (e.g. Apache Ofbiz ERP - source code is usually downloaded and customized for each implementation)
- Blackbox application without extension points
- Blackbox application with extension points for customisation (e.g. MS Word, SAP)
- ...

Is there an established taxonomy of different types of software based on how the software is implemented?

Comment: End users don't "implement" software, developers do that. Do you mean "deployed" or "used"?

Comment: I've removed the reference to end users

Comment: Close voters: Software engineering & development methodologies questions are on topic (don't take my word for it, check out the [FAQ]).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't really a taxonomy: it's a set of orthogonal properties. Some of the most important ones are:

- Open source vs. proprietary
- Publicly available vs. in-house only
- Extensible API or not?
- Plugin support?
- Platform (i.e. what infrastructure does it depend upon)
- Extent of specific customisation for user / company
- Scriptability (i.e. embeds own programming language for users)
- Client type (web vs. desktop GUI vs. console app vs. REST API etc.)
- Monolithic structure vs. composable components?
- Support for distribution (clustering, redundancy failover etc.)
- Stable vs. experimental (in development)

You can have pretty much any combination of the above.... so trying to build it into a tree structure would be fairly pointless as all the branches would need to be duplicated.

Comment: is this list something you have constructed yourself, or is it based on research or any other body of knowledge?

Comment: It's my own list, based on many years of experience rather than any specific research :-) . These are the things I like to know when I'm getting my head around a new software product.

Comment: I started prototyping a software taxonomy. You are welcome to to join and improve it https://unilexicon.com/vocabularies/software/

Answer (score 6):

This is **ancient** but still useful:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/FiveWorlds.html

> I think there are five worlds here, sometimes intersecting, often not.
>   The five are:
>
> - Shrinkwrap
> - Internal
> - Embedded
> - Games
> - Throwaway
>
> When you read the latest book about Extreme Programming, or one of
>   Steve McConnell's excellent books, or Joel on Software, or Software
>   Development magazine, you see a lot of claims about how to do software
>   development, but you hardly ever see any mention of what kind of
>   development they're talking about, which is unfortunate, because
>   sometimes you need to do things differently in different worlds.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a widely accepted taxonomy used in industry, but there are some academic attempts to create one. One example is [by Forward and Lethbridge (ACM subscription required)](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1463807&CFID=272217568&CFTOKEN=19924395). Some software repositories, [such as Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/directory/freshness%3arecently-updated/), provide a categorization scheme for the projects stored within them. At the very least, these schemes may provide a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Most software taxonomies tend to focus on the end user rather than developer interested in implementation aspects.

I compiled a list of those I am aware of in descending order based on how developer v. end-user oriented is the taxonomy.

Free software taxonomies

- **[Software taxonomy](https://unilexicon.com/vocabularies/software/)** on Unilexicon, based on PyPI - collaborative editing welcome
- [Python package index (PyPI) taxonomy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse)
- [Software branch of the DMOZ taxonomy](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Software/)
- [Google Products Taxonomy](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/1705911) has a software branch

Paid taxonomies

- [A taxonomy of software types](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1463807) to facilitate search and evidence-based software engineering
- [WAND Information Technology Taxonomy](http://www.wandinc.com/wand-information-technology-taxonomy.aspx)